# How to detect change in promise value?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I want to poll some function that returns promises and detect change in  resolved values. I need to somehow add `interval` operator here.

```
const observer = (newValue) => {
  console.log('Change detected', newValue);
}

Observable.fromPromise(getValue())
  .distinctUntilChanged((oldValue, newValue) => oldValue == newValue)
  .subscribe(observer);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical case for [`switchMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap)

```
Observable.interval(1000)
  .switchMap(() => Observable.fromPromise(getValue())
  .distinctUntilChanged((oldValue, newValue) => oldValue == newValue)
  .subscribe(observer);
```